# Using LinearOperator as nonlinear constraints in Scipy optimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to use the optimization module in SciPy to solve constrained optimization problem. I need to implement the 'hess' argument. In scipy's documentation and tutorial, their hessian are simply `[[2, 0], [0, 0]]` and `[[2, 0], [0, 0]]`. However, my hessian is something like `[[(-24)*x[0]**2 + 48*x[0]-16, 0], [0, 0]]` and `[[(-48)*x[0]**2 + 192*x[0]-176, 0], [0, 0]]` so that I cannot simply use numpy.array to do multiplication. It seems that I should send a LinearOperator object to the 'hess' arguement. Examples of using LinearOperator is unclear in both [scipy.optimize tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#trust-region-constrained-algorithm-method-trust-constr) and [LinearOperator documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator) since they only show examples of lower dimension. I'm wondering how to correctly use it?

The problem formulation is
[image]

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import Bounds
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    return (-x[0]-x[1])
def grad(x):
    return np.array([-1, -1])
def hess(x):
    return np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

def cons_f(x):
    return [(-2)*x[0]**4 + 8*x[0]**3 + (-8)*x[0]**2 + x[1] -2, (-4)*x[0]**4 + 32*x[0]**3 + (-88)*x[0]**2 + 96*x[0] + x[1] -36]
    
def cons_Jacobian(x):
    return [[(-8)*x[0]**3 + 24*x[0]**2 - 16*x[0], 1], [(-16)*x[0]**3 + 96*x[0]**2 - 176*x[0] +96, 1]]

def cons_Hessian(x,v):
    # TODO
    return v[0]*[[(-24)*x[0]**2 + 48*x[0]-16, 0], [0, 0]] + v[1]*[[(-48)*x[0]**2 + 192*x[0]-176, 0], [0, 0]]

nonlinear_constraint = NonlinearConstraint(cons_f, -np.inf, 0, jac=cons_Jacobian, hess=cons_Hessian)

bounds = Bounds([0, 0], [3.0, 4.0])
x0 = np.array([0.5, 1])
res = minimize(f, x0, method='trust-constr', jac=grad, hess=hess,
               constraints=[nonlinear_constraint],bounds=bounds)
```

The `cons_Hessian(x,v)`is absolutely wrong in my code.

In their example, although hessians are simply`[[2, 0], [0, 0]]` and `[[2, 0], [0, 0]]`, the usage is confusing. I don't understand where p comes in.

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
def cons_H_linear_operator(x, v):
    def matvec(p):
        return np.array([p[0]*2*(v[0]+v[1]), 0])
    return LinearOperator((2, 2), matvec=matvec)
nonlinear_constraint = NonlinearConstraint(cons_f, -np.inf, 1,
                                          jac=cons_J, hess=cons_H_linear_operator)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a LinearOperator. You only need to ensure that `cons_f`, `cons_Jacobian` and `cons_Hessian` return np.ndarrays. That's the reason why you can't evaluate your `cons_Hessian`. Additionally, it's highly recommended to use double literals instead of integers, i.e. `-2.0` instead of `2` to prevent that the function returns np.ndarrays with a integer `dtype`.

Your example works for me by writing these functions as follows:

```py
def cons_f(x):
    con1 = (-2.0)*x[0]**4 + 8*x[0]**3 + (-8)*x[0]**2 + x[1] - 2
    con2 = (-4)*x[0]**4 + 32*x[0]**3 + (-88)*x[0]**2 + 96*x[0] + x[1] -36
    return np.array([con1, con2])
    
def cons_Jacobian(x):
    con1_grad = [(-8.0)*x[0]**3 + 24*x[0]**2 - 16*x[0], 1]
    con2_grad = [(-16)*x[0]**3 + 96*x[0]**2 - 176*x[0] +96, 1]
    return np.array([con1_grad, con2_grad])

def cons_Hessian(x,v):
    con1_hess = np.array([[(-24.0)*x[0]**2 + 48*x[0]-16, 0], [0, 0]])
    con2_hess = np.array([[(-48)*x[0]**2 + 192*x[0]-176, 0], [0, 0]])
    return v[0]*con1_hess + v[1]*con2_hess
```